# First Axiom of Countability and Convergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

I am reading through part of my real analysis book about topology, and it asserts the following theorem:

If a topological space $T$ satisfies the first axiom of countability, then every contact point of a set $M \subset T$ is the limit of a convergent sequence of points in $M$.

The proof then goes on to say that if we can select a sequence of $O_n \in \mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is a countable neighborhood base at some point $x \in [M]$, such that $O_{n+1} \subset O_n$, then we can choose some $x_n$ for each $O_n$ that results in a sequence converging to our desired point $x$. The part that I don't understand is the assumption that we can choose $O_{n+1} \subset O_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Why is this the case? The obvious solution might seem to be to choose some other $G'$ such that there exists some $O' \in \mathcal{O}$ and $O' \subset O$, but what if no such $G'$ exists in the set of open sets of $T$? If the first axiom of countability were to fail because of this, could someone explain it to me?

Any help with this question would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is any countable base at $x$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $V_n=\bigcap_{k=0}^nU_k$; then $\{V_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable base at $x$ such that $V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: But what if there is some smallest set $U_k$ such that $U_k \cap U_n = U_k \hspace{1mm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$? The statement $V_{n+1} \subseteq V_n$ would still hold, but we can't definitively prove that the points $x_n$ that we choose will converge to $x$, right? Or is it an inherent property of a base that such a set $U_k$ doesn't exist? Thanks!

Comment: @user132849: In that case every open nbhd of $x$ contains $U_k$, so that $\{U_k\}$ is a base at $x$. That’s fine: in that case $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ certainly converges to $x$ since every open nbhd of $x$ contains **every** point of the sequence.

Comment: Really? That's very odd haha. I understand what you mean that by definition you can choose infinitely many points in the sequence ${x_n}$ such that each $x_n \in U_k$, but what if the actual sequence converges to some other $x \in U_k$ instead?

Comment: @user132849: It is entirely possible that it converges to **every** point of $U_k$. Here is an example. Let the space be $\Bbb N$ with the indiscrete topology, in which the only open sets are $\varnothing$ and $\Bbb N$ itself. This is certainly first countable: $\{\Bbb N\}$ is a local nbhd base at every point of $\Bbb N$. Let $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any sequence in this space, and let $m\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary. Then for each open nbhd $U$ of $m$ there is a $k_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $n_k\in U$ for all $k\ge k_0$, because the only open nbhd of $m$ is $\Bbb N$, and $n_k\in\Bbb N$ ...

Comment: ... for every $k\ge 0$.

Comment: Very odd. So in this case, this occurs (just to make sure I understood it) because the only open sets here are $\mathbb{N}$ and $\varnothing$ therefore we must choose $\mathbb{N}$ as the open neighborhood in the nbhd base, and therefore any sequence converges to any arbitrary point $m$ by definition?

Comment: And also, so this means that the strict, topological definition of convergence in general topological spaces doesn't necessarily align with our intuitive definition of convergence to a single point the same way that it does in say metric spaces?

Comment: @user132849: That’s what’s happening in this extreme example, but something like it happens whenever some point has an open nbhd that is contained in every nbhd of that point. More generally, there are many spaces with sequences that converge to more than one point, though in Hausdorff spaces this cannot happen.

Comment: That's very fascinating. Thank you so much for your time and your answers!

Comment: @user132849: You’re very welcome.